# What is the difference between <router-view/> and <router-view> </router-view>?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, syntax

I've seen both in different projects, is this simply "syntactic sugar" or are they actually different?

Comment: It's just syntactic sugar just like declaring a custom component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<tag />` is a [self-closing HTML tag](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp). That is the only difference.